# Buddypress member plugin wordpress issue

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using Buddypress plugin for register login and messaging and notification purpose for specific user role type in wordpress.On clicking options in main admin top bar in wordpress options and messages, notification, activity links not working.I am using it with ultimate member plugin wordpress and currently my buddypress form messaging and notification not working.

[image: On clicking Icon on Right hand side shows error page not found]

Comment: Please share some code also or some screenshot of how you are doing it